# lubridate extract object from period inside a function

Tags: r, lubridate

I found this useful function [here](https://gist.github.com/smach/9421294), to compute an age (or just compute the time spent between two dates) :

```
calc_age <- function(birthDate, refDate = Sys.Date()) {


    period <- as.period(new_interval(birthDate, refDate),
                        unit = "year")

    period$year

}
```

I would like to improve it by making the `unit` an argument of the function, so we can get the age in months, days or whatever unit supported by `period` objects.

I tried things like this :

```
calc_age <- function(birthDate, refDate = Sys.Date(), unit = 'year') {


    period <- as.period(new_interval(birthDate, refDate),
                        unit = unit)

    period$unit

}
```

but I'm getting this error message :

`Error in slot(x, name) : 
  no slot of name "unit" for this object of class "Period"`

I think the problem is something related to evaluation so I tried a few things with `enquo` or `quotext` but since I'm pretty new to functionnal programming I couldn't manage to make it work.

Thanks for help and sorry for bad english.

Comment: What exactly are you passing to this function? Please show how you are calling it and give sample input and the desired output for that input.

Comment: Maybe you just want `slot(period, unit)` rather than `period$unit`

Comment: There is no slot `unit`. Return the period, assign to, say, `res <- calc_age(...)` and run `str(res)`. You will see 6 slots but no `"unit"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a big adaptation of the code in the question's link.

```
calc_age2 <- function(birthDate, refDate = Sys.Date(), unit = "year"){
  int <- interval(birthDate, refDate)
  period <- as.period(int, unit = unit)
  slot(period, unit)
}
```

What is the official age of unix?

```
calc_age2("1970-01-01")
#[1] 49
calc_age2("1970-01-01", unit = "month")
#[1] 593
```